# Implementing the DllRegisterServer method

Tags: c++, com, dllregistration

I'm trying to implement a COM's DllRegisterServer method.
So I read this tutorial:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm

and I followed the steps until the part of DllRegisterServer.
This is their implementation:

```
HRESULT  __stdcall DllRegisterServer(void)
    {
    //
    //As per COM guidelines, every self installable COM inprocess component
    //should export the function DllRegisterServer for printing the 
    //specified information to the registry
    //
    //

    WCHAR *lpwszClsid;
    char szBuff[MAX_PATH]="";
    char szClsid[MAX_PATH]="", szInproc[MAX_PATH]="",szProgId[MAX_PATH];
    char szDescriptionVal[256]="";

    StringFromCLSID(
            CLSID_AddObject,
            &lpwszClsid);

    wsprintf(szClsid,"%S",lpwszClsid);
    wsprintf(szInproc,"%s\\%s\\%s","clsid",szClsid,"InprocServer32");
    wsprintf(szProgId,"%s\\%s\\%s","clsid",szClsid,"ProgId");


    //
    //write the default value 
    //
    wsprintf(szBuff,"%s","Fast Addition Algorithm");
    wsprintf(szDescriptionVal,"%s\\%s","clsid",szClsid);

    HelperWriteKey (
                HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                szDescriptionVal,
                NULL,//write to the "default" value
                REG_SZ,
                (void*)szBuff,
                lstrlen(szBuff)
                );


    //
    //write the "InprocServer32" key data
    //
    GetModuleFileName(
                g_hModule,
                szBuff,
                sizeof(szBuff));
    HelperWriteKey (
                HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                szInproc,
                NULL,//write to the "default" value
                REG_SZ,
                (void*)szBuff,
                lstrlen(szBuff)
                );

    //
    //write the "ProgId" key data under HKCR\clsid\{---}\ProgId
    //
    lstrcpy(szBuff,AddObjProgId);
    HelperWriteKey (
                HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                szProgId,
                NULL,
                REG_SZ,
                (void*)szBuff,
                lstrlen(szBuff)
                );


    //
    //write the "ProgId" data under HKCR\CodeGuru.FastAddition
    //
    wsprintf(szBuff,"%s","Fast Addition Algorithm");
    HelperWriteKey (
                HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                AddObjProgId,
                NULL,
                REG_SZ,
                (void*)szBuff,
                lstrlen(szBuff)
                );


    wsprintf(szProgId,"%s\\%s",AddObjProgId,"CLSID");
    HelperWriteKey (
                HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                szProgId,
                NULL,
                REG_SZ,
                (void*)szClsid,
                lstrlen(szClsid)
                );

    return 1;

    }
```

where CLSID_AddObject is defined like this:

```
// {92E7A9C2-F4CB-11d4-825D-00104B3646C0}
static const GUID CLSID_AddObject = 
{ 0x92e7a9c2, 0xf4cb, 0x11d4, { 0x82, 0x5d, 0x0, 0x10, 0x4b, 0x36, 0x46, 0xc0 } };
```

What I don't understand is:
 1. Why do they use `StringFromCLSID` to get the GUID as string? They already have it and for some reason they convert it to IID? isn't the GUID we give it in the IDL file good enough?
 2. Which GUIDs need to be registered? Ther library's GUID? the interfaces' GUIDs? the classes GUIDs? or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why a GUID is converted to a string is that it's used to form some entries in the Windows Registry. You may see in your example code how the CLSID string gets incorporated into `InprocServer32`, `ProgId`, and `CLSID` entries.

You should register all the GUIDs in the Registry. You may have a look at [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details about COM Registry keys.

Comment: ok, but why do they use StringFromCLSID instead of just using "{92E7A9C2-F4CB-11d4-825D-00104B3646C0}" ?

Comment: There is a dedicated type `GUID` (it is not a string). A value of this type is generated for you and defined in a header file in a single place. Where do you see the same GUID value defined as a plain string?

Comment: In the someting_h.h file it says: class DECLSPEC_UUID("some guid")

Comment: @Idov follow that macro and you'll see it pins the GUID to the struct/class it is marking via an extension the the MSVC implementation of the language. Also understand that "string" is generated by the MIDL compiler; the *code* you see for DllRegisterServer is generated by the ATL project wizard. Two entirely different pieces of functionality.

Comment: I'm using VS express, so I don't have the ATL project wizard. But I still don't understand. Into the registry I'm supposed the write the GUID as string. I already have this GUID as string, so why use "StringFromCLSID"? oh, and I'm using GUIDs generated by the UUIDGEN website. I didn't see that MIDL generated GUIDs for me...

Comment: @Idov Again, *you* don't have the guid as a string. All you have is an extern CLSID declared in a _h.h file and defined in the _i.c file. MIDL generated that code specifically for tagging the struct; nothing more. Since all *you* have access to is a CLSID, you need to use the API to convert it to a string.

Comment: @Idov, because the GUID is defined as a value of GUID type and it's done in a single place, you have this value and then you can do with it anything you need, including conversion to string for registration in the Registry. The GUID is a primary entity, the string is a secondary.